# VBA code to display message based on cell value in a range of cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to VBA. I am trying to create a macro that will display a message based on cell value from a range of cells on a different sheet.I already have a macro that essentially is a ctlr + F and the goal is that when that ID number is entered this new macro will display a desired message.

This is what I have and as you can tell I'm very new and probably isn't even close to what I need:

```
Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    If Worksheets("worksheet").range("B2:B200") > 0 Then
        MsgBox "message needed"
    Else
        MsgBox "other message needed"
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

In theory if there is a 0 in the cell that was searched from the range of cells in the first macro, then it will display a message, otherwise it will display an alternative message.

Comment: You can't do that comparison on a multi-cell range. Perhaps use `WorksheetFunction.CountIf` on that range, with 0 as the criterion.

Comment: So your goal is to determine if you either throw an error or you have `.find() is nothing`?  What is your ctrl+f macro?  that may be the key here... `set f = .find()` then `if f is nothing then`

Answer (score 1):

The `Worksheet_Calculate` handler (which should be `Private`) will execute *every single time* anything is calculated on that worksheet.

> *the goal is that when that ID number is entered this new macro will...*

Use the `Worksheet_Change` handler for that. You'll get a `ByVal Target As Range` parameter that tells you which cell(s) was/were modified; you can use `Application.Intersect` to determine whether `Target` intersects with a particular range of cells, and act accordingly - there are plenty of examples on this site.

Now, this code:

> ```
> If Worksheets("BLD Id List To Be Searched").Range("B2:B200") > 0 Then
> ```

Is implicitly taking the `Value` of a multi-cell `Range` object, which is a 2D variant array - and then comparing it to `0`. That's a guaranteed *type mismatch* run-time error, because you can't compare a whole array with a single value like this.

Take @BigBen's advice here:

```
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf([ActiveWorkbook.]Worksheets("name").Range("B2:B200"), ">0") > 0 Then
```

Note that if you mean to work with `ThisWorkbook` (i.e. the Excel document that contains the VBA code), and the worksheet "BLD ID list to be searched" exists at compile-time in `ThisWorkbook`, then the code would be more robust / user-proof if you used the sheet's code name instead of dereferencing it from the `Worksheets` collection of whatever workbook happens to be active at the time, using its user-modifiable "tab name".

Change the worksheet module's `(Name)` property to e.g. `BLDListSheet`, and then you can do this:

```
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(BLDListSheet.Range("B2:B200"), ">0") > 0 Then
```

And never need to worry about keeping the code in sync with the sheet's "tab name".

Now, if the macro runs *every time* a cell is modified, it doesn't make much sense to show a message and ignore which particular cell was modified, does it?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Application.Intersect(BLDListSheet.Range("B2:B200"), Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If IsNumeric(Target.Value) Then
        If Target.Value > 0 Then
            ' modified cell has a new value greater than 0
        Else
            ' modified cell has a new value less than or equal to 0
        End If
    Else
        ' Target.Value may not be safe to compare with anything here.
        If IsError(Target.Value) Then Debug.Print Target.Address & " contains an error!"
    End If
End Sub
```